# What Data Structure to use (in JAVA) with 3 sets of keys in random order

Tags: java, data-structures

I have 3 sets of keys: one is  type, another is subtype and the last one is ID and value is a ProductObj. Originally, I thought of storing the ProductObj in HashMap of HashMap of HashMap (`HashMap<type, HashMap<subtype, HashMap<ID, prodObj>>>`) for faster search (want to design this as a Cache instead of keep retrieving from the DB). [Note: # of productObj is fixed] However, I learned that 50% of the time, I might only get ID and not type/subtype and another 50% would be type/subtype but no ID. What would be a good data structure to suit such purpose?

I thought of `HashMap<type, HashMap<subtype, HashMap<ID, uuid>>>` and another `HashMap<uuid, prodObj>`, but I hope to find a even better solution in terms of the data structure. Thanks in advance!

[Additional information]

This is what hope to store {type=1 subtype=1 id=1=prodObj1, type=1 subtype=1 id=2=prodObj2,...}

When id is given: e.g. id=1, then prodObj1 is returned

When type is given: e.g. type=1, the both prodObj1 and prodObj2 are returned

When type & subtype are given: e.g. type=1 subtype=1, the both prodObj1 and prodObj2 are returned

When type, subtype & id are given: e.g. type=1 subtype=1 id=1, then prodObj1 is returned

I hope to utilize a HashMap like data structure for faster search based on a key value as I will access the cache and change the prodObj state often.

Comment: I'd recommend a Dictionary. It may nor be the most efficient, but it is easy to use. Here is the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Dictionary.html

Comment: @Jsleshem why do you think that would be better than `HashMap`s? Especially given the documentation says "NOTE: This class is obsolete".

Comment: Are those 3 keys a composite key so that every combination only exists once?

Comment: Are the subtypes and ids globally unique or is only the combination of all 3 parts unique? If they are globally unique you could use 3 maps (it would be a `Map<key, Set<prodObj>>` or better one of Guava's `Multimap` implementations) and you get the values for the keys that are provided and return the intersection of those result sets.

Comment: @AndyTurner I've been using dictionary for a while. Maybe it is time for me to switch to a HashMap

Comment: @Jsleshem, it definitely is the time. Long past the time, in fact. Unless you specifically need something that disctionary did and maps do not (which I can't really think of anything, tbh).

Comment: I did some research, and like the documentation said the data type is obsolete. There is nothing a dictionary does that a hash cannot do as well. Thanks OP!

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS yes, id is unique for sure. type + subtype + id will be unique

Comment: I have updated my question with examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why using nested maps ?

If you don't manipulate a huge number of values in your map, you could use as key a custom class that defines a composite key (type, subtype and id).

In this way, you could pass to your map an instance of this composite key when you get from or put in.

```
public class ProductKey{

  private Long id;
  private string type;
  private string subType;

  private ProductKey(){
  }

  public static ProductKey ofWithId(Long id){
    ProductKey productKey = new ProductKey();
    productKey.id = id;  
    return productKey;
  }
   ...
  // other factory methods
   ...
  // equals and hashcode overriden of course
}
```

And  you could instantiate and populate your map in this way :

```
Map<ProductKey, ProductObj> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(ProductKey.ofWithId(1), myProductObj);
map.put(ProductKey.ofWithTypeAndSubType("type", "subtype"), anotherProductObj);
 ...
```

And retrieve element in this way :

```
 ProductObj retrievedObj = map.get(ProductKey.ofWithId(1));
```

Comment: Assuming there are multiple products per subtype you'd need to use collections as map values.

Comment: @Thomas You are totally right. According to the real need, using a collection as value could be  suitable. But the general idea stays valid I think.

Comment: Yes I agree single HashMap is better. was hoping to utilize the key "index" for HashMap. Thanks!

Comment: @davidxxx  I actually need to populate all 3 keys in the product key just the search is different. If I store a ProductKey (say : type=1, subtype=1 and id=1 -> prodObj1), then during search only id=1 is given, how can I find prodObj1? This is the part I am not clear and I didn't use this as the key. maybe I misunderstand something. could you please advice?

Comment: You are welcome. It depends on your model. Is id with the 1 value is unique ?  Or is there other product with id 1 but other type and subtype ?

Comment: id is always unique, type and subtype can be dupes e.g. {type=1 subtype=1 id=1}, {type=1 subtype=1 id=2} etc

Comment: Ok. So if you provide type=1 and subtype=1 as input, you can retrieve multiple objects ?

Comment: @davidxxx the thing I am unsure is: say I only have id=1, I create ProdKey(type=-1, subtype=-1, id=1)  [note: 0<type 0<= subtype 0<id] , with Prodkey as the key of a HashMap, I am not sure I can retrieve the object I want

Comment: @davidxxx yes if only given type and subtype, I would get a list of objects. if given type, subtype and id, I would get the object. If given id, I would get  the object as well.

Comment: don't hesitate to edit your question to add this model specifications. This could do the Q/An more helpful for others.

Comment: I will do that. id is not required all the time though. I will modify my question to make it more clear.

Comment: After thinking about it, with this requirement, it is indeed not feasible with this implementation.This implementation supposes that you use the same key for get and map operations. To implement your requirement, you should introduce another structures. Maybe 2 maps could do the job: one that has the id as key and another one that has the type and the subtype as key. In this way you will query the one or the second according to the request (id or type-subtype).

Comment: @davidxxx thanks! I was hoping to avoid 2 maps (hence I was thinking about nested maps, but it didn't work as what I would hope for.)

Comment: Come to think of it, type and subtype as key, won't give me fast access if I am given type only (as I still need to get something like ProdKey.getType == targetType)  Does that mean i need to have 3 maps, one is type->obj, another is type and subtype ->obj, and last one is id->obj?

Comment: If you need also to request with only a type, you have 3 type of requests. So indeed, to have a fast access, using three distinct maps seems better. This solution will however have a cost in terms of memory consumption.

Comment: I think that with the initial solution and our comments, you have a idea on how to solve the problem. It becomes very hot at home. I have to turn off my pc. Sorry. If you have some difficulties to implement the solution and you don't have any other helpful answers, don't hesitate to make me a comment. I will see it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a single HashMap.  Make the key of the map a combination of the three values.

The simplest would be as a String using a delimiter that won't be used in any of the values.  For example, using Java 8:

```
String key = String.join(":", type, subType, id) ;
productMap.put(key, product) ;
```

The join method is null safe, so it is fine if those values are missing.

Comment: I too prefer single map.